# Can CSS source maps be in a sub directory

Tags: source-maps, postcss

I want my source maps to be a in sub directory, relative to the CSS directory, e.g.

```
styles/css/components/
styles/css/components/maps/
```

With the source map comment for my base.css

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=maps/base.css.map */
```

Reading the docs at Google I get the impression that source maps simply need a relative path (I assume relative to the CSS directory), however no browser seems to be able to read this URL, **what am I doing wrong**?

I'm using PostCSS btw, my code is:

```
postcss: {
  css: {
    src: 'styles/css/components/**.css',
    options: {
      map: {
        inline: false,
        annotation: 'styles/css/components/maps/',
      },
      processors: [
        require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'})
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use gulp, this plugin helps you https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plugin1 = require('gulp-plugin1');
var plugin2 = require('gulp-plugin2');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plugin1())
      .pipe(plugin2())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```